# How to call fork() with flags or clone() without the first argument fn?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I'd like to call `fork()` with flag `CLONE_PARENT`, however, I can't find a way to do that.

`clone()` may be a good alternative in most situations, but I'd like to call `fork()` in a signal handler and go back to previous flow after the signal handler finished.

I may change the kernel, so any solution need kernel modification is ok.

I tried to call syscall `clone` directly, but I don't know how to get a `struct pt_regs` in user space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `clone`.  While the `fork` `syscall` still exists, under newer versions of `glibc`, the `fork` library call is just a linker alias to `clone` with some special arguments

For anything [well, most things] you don't have you can pass `NULL`

Here's a little snippet to start from:

```
#define ARCH_FORK() \
  INLINE_SYSCALL (clone, 4,                                                   \
                  CLONE_CHILD_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD, 0,     \
                  NULL, &THREAD_SELF->tid)
```

Comment: I tracked the code you cited and I think the asm code does a thing like `syscall(__NR_clone, CLONE_CHILD_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD, 0, NULL, &THREAD_SELF->tid)`. I tested the code above, however, the child process and parent process both got the pid of parent when calling `getpid()`. If I call `fork()` instead, `getpid()` returns the correct pid of child process.

Comment: `syscall clone` needs 5 arguments in fact. Is the incorrect result above caused by the missing argument `pt_regs`?

Comment: @oryxfea You'll just have to experiment a bit.  The glibc wrapper to the clone syscall takes different arguments, and can take 4-6 arguments.  The clone syscall itself takes exactly 5 arguments.  When you build, figure out which one you're hooked up to.  Look at the clone man page, it will describe the differences in detail.  For raw, you may have to specify the prototype or use syscall(...).  The wrapper doesn't use pt_regs  ARCH_FORK uses the raw syscall.  See sysdeps/nptl/fork.c and __libc_fork.  Notice that it does quite a lot more than just clone.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that I missed some code in `__libc_fork()` which changes the pid of new process. But I still have the question about the argument count of clone syscall. Is  `ARCH_FORK()` the same as the code I tested above? If so, doesn't it miss the argument `pt_regs`?

Comment: @oryxfea Find the ARCH_FORK that matches the arch you're using--they _are_ different.  ARCH_FORK uses the raw syscall, so you can replace the INLINE_SYSCALL with `syscall(__NR_clone,...)`.  If you haven't already, create a simple test program that _just_ does your "special_fork()" in isolation.  You could/should, just cut-n-paste the guts of ARCH_FORK into your function.  Try all combos, but I suspect just adding the flag you want gets you pretty close.  If you have to, borrow as much of `__libc_fork` as you need. What you're doing is non-standard so take the pain :-)

Comment: I think I've found the `ARCH_FORK()` I am using. It's the same as you cite. My problem has been solved since you have told me so much. I'm just confused about the argument count. Since it is  a new question, I may open a new thread. Thank you for your help : )

Comment: @oryxfea Congrats.  I'm curious.  I realize what the flag does.  But, what specific effect and/or process hierarchy were you trying for?  How does it differ from child doing setpgid/setpgrp?  Did you want child to fork subchild that was owned by parent?  That is, after fork, child goes away, but subchild can be reaped by parent (vs pid 1)?  If so, I've usually done that by child sending [IPC] msg to parent requesting parent do the fork+whatever.  Would that have worked for you?  I sometimes do non-standard fork/thread stuff myself, so I'm interested for my own benefit as well.

Comment: I just want child clones itself. The process hierarchy is quite simple, which is a robust parent and its many children. In normal situations, making child sending `msg` to parent before it exits is fine. But for me, the children may exit for any reason. I don't expect it exits normally. BTW, I'm not sure what do you mean of `requesting parent do the fork+whatever`. Can parent fork a child? If so, this will be good news for me.

Comment: @oryxfea So, you have master/parent M.  It forks child A.  A forks B which you want owned by M vs A--hence the CLONE_PARENT.  You want M>A,M>B vs M>A>B.  Depends on what A _has_ done and what you want B to do.  msg _not_ sent by A/B at exit.  My way:  When A wants B, it sends msg to M, and M forks B and you get M>A,M>B.  This works if A has not changed too much since being forked by M.  Also works if A's msg has updated data that B uses for setup after being forked.  How many variables has A changed, etc?  I believe I've done similar before.

Comment: Your way is roughly the same with mine expect I use signal rather than IPC msg. M is different from A/B. A will call `execv()` to execute another program, whose source code expects to be unmodified. I use library to add signal handler to A/B. However, if I want to use IPC msg, I have to change the whole A/B program to a non-blocking way to recv IPC msg asyc, am I right?